# Compacting this repetitive JavaScript bit which trims values in an object

Tags: javascript

```
    shippingAddress.first_name = shippingAddress.first_name.trim()
    shippingAddress.last_name = shippingAddress.last_name.trim()
    shippingAddress.address1 = shippingAddress.address1.trim()
    shippingAddress.address2 = shippingAddress.address2.trim()
    shippingAddress.phone = shippingAddress.phone.trim()
    shippingAddress.city = shippingAddress.city.trim()
    shippingAddress.province = shippingAddress.province.trim()
    shippingAddress.country = shippingAddress.country.trim()
    shippingAddress.zip = shippingAddress.zip.trim()
```

What is a more elegant way to write this? I am thinking I can map it somehow or use something similar to Ruby's `inject` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single traversal on *keys* list and trimming all fields of type `string`:

```
Object.keys(shippingAddress).forEach((k) => {
    if (typeof shippingAddress[k] == 'string') {
        shippingAddress[k] = shippingAddress[k].trim();
    }
})
```

Comment: Why is ForEach a superior choice to a for loop?

Comment: @McDerp, with `for` loop you would have to declare additional counter variables and control condition checked on each iteration. You don't need that when dealing with object keys

Comment: Is trimming this best done in a function that is mapped to a http action or is this function best abstracted to a /utils/misc.js or something like that?